# How to integrate multiple payment gateway ( Multiple merchant ) in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, authorize.net, payflowpro, cybersource

As i'm new in ruby on rails so sorry for silly question if it is.
I'm developing e-commerse application like amazon. So seller needs to add their merchant account in rails application. Merchant acccount can be paypalpaylfow, authorize.net or cybersource. I want to integrate  PayPal Payflow, Authorize.net, CyberSource. I realy don't know about any of these payment gateway. So can anyone help me out? Can you provide me the solutions or examples for the above payment gateway.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you got so far, could you show something you started doing?

Comment: I read https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/#payouts-flow and https://www.authorize.net/. But I can't understand so far.

Answer (score 0):

To get started with PayPal Payflow gateway, you should review the guide at this website:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/

The link you provided in the comment on your original post is for "payouts" which is different than "Payflow".

Answer (score 0):

You can look into ActiveMerchant. If you have a problem with payload and ruby versions you can browse their unit test cases and start trace from there.

https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/test/unit/gateways/cyber_source_test.rb

https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/test/unit/gateways/authorize_net_test.rb

https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/test/unit/gateways/payflow_test.rb